# In PyCharm, how do I debug a JavaScript file that's accessed from a template-driven site?

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm to debug a JavaScript file. When I bring up the debug dialog for the JavaScript file in question, I'm presented with a dialog where I must enter the HTML file that launches the JavaScript file.

Of course, the JavaScript file isn't launched from a static HTML page, but from some Python that uses templates. But it wants a static HTML file to initiate debugging.

Am I missing something, or debugging JavaScript that's invoked from a dynamic page not possible in PyCharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **JavaScript Debug** configuration type it's possible to specify any URL that you want, PyCharm will open a browser for you.

In the **Debug** panel **Scripts** tab load the script that you want to debug and place the breakpoints in the downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by the JavaScript Debug configuration? In the Edit Configuration screen that appears when you debug, I see the following fields: "Name", "HTML File", "Browser", "Show Settings (Before Launch)", and Share Configuration. The HTML File field seems to want to take a local path.

Comment: There is JavaScript Remote configuration, press [+] button to create one: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap0941-1329516234.png.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you map folders to URLs. Thanks!